# Get overlaped time range with conditions

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I m trying to make a scheduler of tasks, but I ran into a problem that don't know what to do or how to solve :S

I'll try to explain as best as I can.
given a table like following:

```
key | start |  end  | employee(fk) 
 1    6:00    8:00     A               
 2    9:00    11:00    B
 3    7:00    9:00     B
 4    7:00    11:00    C
```

[image: in image]

what I want to find is, given a set of N employees, return me all overlaped time range by those given employees. it's kind like get "AND'ed" row of given employees. (or in other word: get all time range which all the given employees are working)

Example:

```
given {A,B}   returns 2 columns 7:00  |  8:00  time range which overlaped by A and B
given {B,C}  returns  2 columns 9:00  |  11:00  time range which overlaped by B and C
```

I have been thinking for 3 days and still not very clear idea what to do... can someone help me?

Comment: What kind of granularity you need? Half an hour? An hour? One minute?

Comment: half hour will be fine, but that affects on something?

Comment: yeah, cause you can easily discretize everything with steps being sure not to have to do many of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your granularity is enough coarse you could just go with steps of 30 minutes and check wether every employee is actually busy.

You could keep an array of boolean values, one for every employee, which tells if that employee is busy at current time.

Then you go with steps of 30 minutes (let's suppose from 6AM):

1. you check who starts their activity at 6AM, for every starting activity you set true to the corresponding flag
2. if all the flags are set to true then here you have a starting overlapping range, otherwise , if an overlapping range was going, stop it
3. increase time by 30 minutes
4. for every starting activity of an employee set his flag to true
5. for every ending activity of an employee set his flag to false
6. go back to step 2

Comment: but isn't that too much process checking every 30min? because I don't want to get only time range of a single day, I need time range in at least 3 months or 1 years if possible.

Comment: You will have to explore all the activities for sure. By manipulating data directly it would be easy: just keep them sorted so that you actually extract them in right order without the need of going by steps of 30 mins (you will extract every time someone starts or stops an activity) but with queries I don't think there is a quick way. You need to do a complex operation indeed.

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves it in psuedo-SQL (I use my company's home-brewed DB, so use our SQL syntax). Assuming table name "Table" :

```
SELECT T1.employee, T2.employee, T1.start, T2.end 
FROM Table T1, Table T2 
WHERE T1.key!=T2.key AND T1.employee!=T2.employee 
      AND T1.start <= T2.end AND T1.start >= T2.start
```